# Is reversing part of python list in place

Tags: python, list, reverse

Does reversing part of the array in the following manner create a copy of array from i to j?

```
a[i:j] = a[i:j][::-1] # is this in place? Does this operation require O(j-i) space
```

Does following code not take any extra space?

```
a[i:j] = reversed(a[i,j])
```

So is there any other way to reverse part of list with O(1) space apart from following code?

```
for k in range(i, i + (j-i + 1)//2):
  arr[k], arr[j-k] = arr[j-k], arr[k]
```

Comment: You can swap things in Python without a temporary location, eg `arr[k], arr[j-k] = arr[j-k], arr[k]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of. `a` is modified in place, but `a[i:j]` creates a new list object, as does applying `[::-1]` to `a[i:j]`.

```
b = a[i:j]  # new list object
b = b[::-1] # another new list object
a[i:j] = b  # modifies a in place
```

Comment: so are you saying it requires additional O(j-i) space?

Comment: Yes; the only way to use less space is to swap one pair of elements at a time in a loop, using O(1) space (i.e., independent of `i` and `j`).

Comment: There could be a way to reverse a part of a list if the reverse method could have arguments for 'start' and 'end' positions in the list - that is, your_list.reverse() - but as of today, there is no such implementation